# UNITY: Vector3 with doubles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I want to increase the size if an object whenever there is a collision with another game object. I use this script:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)  //Unity function called when a collision is detected, and the object collided is put into the variable 'col' to be used later
 {
     if(other.gameObject.tag == "enemy")   //if the object you collided with is the enemy
     {
         transform.localScale += new Vector3 (1,1,1); //increase the size of the ball
         Destroy(other.gameObject);  //Destroy the enemy
     }
 
}
}
```

The problem is: the object that I want to increase gets to big to quickly. I tried putting in doubles but of course that doesn't work. Does anyone have a workaround?

best regards
bigchungus

Comment: YSK that `1.0` is detected as a `double` by C#, which is not supported by `Vector3`. `1.0f` is detected as a `float`, which *is* supported by `Vector3`. `double` is 64-bit and quite expensive to compute many times per frame for all of the physics & graphics in a game. Graphics cards can handle variables with 32-bit `float` quite a bit faster than the 64-bit `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches.

you could increase the value with a smaller (fixed) amount. This uses `floats` not `doubles`.

```
transform.localScale += new Vector3 (0.1f,0.1f,0.1f); // Increase size by a fixed 0.1f on all dimensions
```

You could also multiply the scale by a float value

```
transform.localScale *= 1.1f; // increases size by 10% each time
```